# Beta goes public on Wednesday

Tags: discussion

[According to Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2305/bicycles), this site goes to public beta in 4 days (on Wednesday Septeber 1st).

What do we absolutely need to tackle in those four days? Do we need to do anything at all? Some of the 7 essential questions have been posted and discussed, but let's triage the rest.

Comment: How do we edit the FAQ? It would be good to add some info about tagging - I'm keen on the use of proper terminology for tags to avoid tag dilution (http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/38/how-to-manage-duplicate-tags/40#40)

Comment: Should also add a link to the terminology question into the FAQ (http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index)

Comment: It looks like we're not live today, but I don't know why. [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63146/bicycles-site-public-beta-deferred](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63146/bicycles-site-public-beta-deferred)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### FAQ and on/off topic:

I don't think we need to have the FAQ quite ready, most of the other public betas I spend time on didn't have one when they went public -- but we should have discussed the issues of what's on and off topic. We've made a good start on this, I think, and need to keep pursuing questions like these: https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-off-topic

If there's anyone here with pet issues, like car-free cycling or BMX bikes, you might want to start asking questions on the main site or posting something in Meta about what the limits of he topic are -- or do both, as the subject warrants. Keep in mind that, if there are questions about [topic x] here on Wednesday when the beta goes live, then people from the main SE sites interested in [topic x] will be more likely to stick around.

Comment: I thought this site might be useful for bmx, but the more I check back the more I realize that I'm not really interested at all in cycling...only bmx riding. so meh...it is what it is.

Comment: @dotjoe: I'm not sure what you mean by that. A BMX is a kind of bicycle.

Comment: By cycling, I guess I mean people who use the bike for commuting or for traveling long distances. Where by bmx riding, I mean dirt jumps, ramps, and street riding.

Comment: @dotjoe: I think it would be great is we could get some BMX questions in here. Please, post some questions! And if you know of some places to [publicize the board](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/41/site-promotion-for-public-beta) that would attract BMX riders, that'd be great too.